# Get trouble when using `cutwin` package with theorem environment and math mode to wrap figure

Tags: wrapfigure

I'm using `cutwin` package to display some math formula and figure.

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{tikz,pgf}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{cutwin}
  \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\opencutright
\begin{thm}[When I use math mode]
\renewcommand*{\windowpagestuff}{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=.9cm,y=.9cm]
\draw [line width=1.pt] (0.,4.)-- (-2.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (-2.,0.)-- (4.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (4.,0.)-- (0.,4.);
);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=white] (0.,4.) circle (1.pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.026126988496250766,4.215760772695029) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=white] (-2.,0.) circle (1.pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.2,-0.1) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=white] (4.,0.) circle (1.pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.15,-0.1) node {$C$};
\end{scriptsize}

\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{cutout}{0}{.5\linewidth}{1pt}{8}
Given $ABC$ be a triangle with $BC=a$, $CA=b$, $AB=c$. Prove that:
\begin{align*}
\cos A=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}
\end{align*}
\end{cutout}
\end{thm}


\begin{thm}[When I use list environment]
\renewcommand*{\windowpagestuff}{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=.9cm,y=.9cm]
\draw [line width=1.pt] (0.,4.)-- (-2.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (-2.,0.)-- (4.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (4.,0.)-- (0.,4.);
);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=white] (0.,4.) circle (1.pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.026126988496250766,4.215760772695029) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=white] (-2.,0.) circle (1.pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.2,-0.1) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=white] (4.,0.) circle (1.pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.15,-0.1) node {$C$};
\end{scriptsize}

\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{cutout}{0}{.5\linewidth}{1pt}{8}
Given $ABC$ be a triangle with $BC=a$, $CA=b$, $AB=c$. Prove that:

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{wrong} \lipsum[1]
\item \textbf{wrong} something...
\end{enumerate}
\end{cutout}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

I got below trouble while I was using other environments inside `cutout` environment.

[image]

What should I do or which package should I use to fix that missing? Thank for your help!

Comment: Why don't you use `wrapfig`?

Comment: I used to use 'wrapfig'  but cannot use it with other environment such as theorem. Can you teach me how to use `wrapfig`?

Comment: Any one can help me?